# Handling checkbox using Enter Key in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning Vue.js. In my App, I have created a form with multiple checkbox with search. When user **focus a checkbox using tab key and press enter key in keyboard then checkbox should be selected**.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(ingredient, index) in filteredIngredients" :key="index" class="list-group-item px-md-4">
      <div class="row px-3">
        <div class="col-auto">
          <input v-model="ingredient.checkbox" 
            class="form-check-input" 
            type="checkbox" 
            @focus="checkFocus"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col ps-0">
          <span class="mb-2 d-block text-gray-800">
            <strong class="text-black-600">{{ ingredient.name }}</strong>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    methods: {
      checkFocus(event) {
        // what can I do here
      },
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Working while using space key in keyboard. But it should work using enter key.

Comment: Please share the relevant code.

Comment: Please read how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want to do it with the method you made.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      filteredIngredients: [
        {name: "paper", checkbox: false},
        {name: "salt", checkbox: false}
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkFocus(index) {
      this.filteredIngredients[index].checkbox = true;
    },
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="list-group-item px-md-4" v-for="(ingredient,index) in filteredIngredients" :key="index">
      <div class="row px-3">
          <div class="col-auto">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                @keyup.enter="checkFocus(index)"
                v-model="ingredient.checkbox"
              />
          </div>
          <div class="col ps-0">
              <span class="mb-2 d-block text-gray-800">
                  <strong class="text-black-600">{{ingredient.name}}</strong>
              </span>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and if you want to do it with enter key you can use **@keyup.enter** instead of **@focus**.

Comment: Niaz, based on your code checkbox will checked when focus to checkbox. But in my case checkbox should be checked after  press enter key in keyboard.

Comment: @kariyadan So use the code that I just edited.